# Hortonworks sandbox Install on LinuxVM?

Tags: hadoop, installation, hortonworks-sandbox

How to install hortonworks sandbox on LinuxVM? Any video tutorials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: On the HortonWorks site they have a tutorial - https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/

Comment: Hi Brad. Is the installation straight forward ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hortonworks Sandbox Installation on Oracle Virtual Machine:**

Download HDP sandbox from [here](https://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/) and extract it.

Download Virtual Box from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) AND Install Virtual Box on Windows.

Now Open Oracle Virtual Box and go to File "Menu" and click on "Import Appliance".

[image]

Set Name, CPU, RAM etc. as per your configuration and Click on "Import" button.
(It will take time. Please wait for it.)

[image]

After installation, following Window will appear.

[image]
Press Alt+F5.
Login as `root` as a username and `hadoop` as a password.(Both are Default.)

[image]

And at next step, it will ask for change the password.

```
(Current) UNIX password: <old_password> //hadoop    
New password: <New_Password>    
Retype Password:<New_Password>
```

Now, you have to reset "Ambari" password as well.

So, on `root` user execute the following command.

```
[root@abc]# ambari-admin-password-reset

Please set the password for admin : <New_Password_for_Ambari>
Please retype the password for admin : <New_Password_for_Ambari>
```

And Ambari will restart again.

Now Goto the Ambari at http://localhost:8080
enter your `Username` and `Password`.
Your **Hortonworks** sandbox has been Installed on VM.

NOTE: If you have any concerns ask anytime.